# PHP: using IF to run a function

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I have been editing an order receipt printing plugin within WordPress/WooCommerce. I have good HTML understanding but my PHP is almost non-existent so I have come to a stumbling block which I hope will be easy for someone to point me in the right direction.

I have added the first, second and last lines of code. The existing remaining code is a function to print the customer's billing/shipping address.

Most orders are going to be pickup and the address will be surplus information so I have made a variable (which works by displaying 'pickup' or 'delivery' as text in another edit I did earlier), then I intended the function to run only if the variable was equal to 'delivery' and I do not want the function to run/exist if the value is anything different. This is my failed attempt if someone could please help:

```
$swift_order_type = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_zh_shipping_type') ? get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_zh_shipping_type')[0] : '';;

if ($swift_order_type == delivery ){
    function star_cloudprnt_print_address(&$printer, &$selectedPrinter, &$order, &$order_meta)
    {
        // function to get address values if they exist or return an empty string
        $gkv = function($key) use ($order_meta) {
            if(array_key_exists($key, $order_meta))
                return $order_meta[$key][0];

            return '';
        };

        $fname = $gkv('_shipping_first_name');
        $lname = $gkv('_shipping_last_name');
        $a1 = $gkv('_shipping_address_1');
        $a2 = $gkv('_shipping_address_2');
        $city = $gkv('_shipping_city');
        $state = $gkv('_shipping_state');
        $postcode = $gkv('_shipping_postcode');
        $tel = $gkv('_billing_phone');
        
        $printer->add_new_line(1);

        $printer->set_text_emphasized();
        if ($a1 == '')
        {
            $printer->add_text_line("Billing Address:");
            $printer->cancel_text_emphasized();
            $fname = $gkv('_billing_first_name');
            $lname = $gkv('_billing_last_name');
            $a1 = $gkv('_billing_address_1');
        
            $a2 = $gkv('_billing_address_2');
            $city = $gkv('_billing_city');
            $state = $gkv('_billing_state');
            $postcode = $gkv('_billing_postcode');
        }
        else
        {
            $printer->add_text_line("Delivery Address:");
            $printer->cancel_text_emphasized();
        }
        
        $printer->add_text_line($fname." ".$lname);
        $printer->add_text_line($a1);
        if ($a2 != '') $printer->add_text_line($a2);
        if ($city != '') $printer->add_text_line($city);
        if ($state != '') $printer->add_text_line($state);
        if ($postcode != '') $printer->add_text_line($postcode);

        $printer->add_text_line("Tel: ".$tel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't put the function definition in the `if`, put the code that *calls* the function there.

Comment: There's no need to declare all the function parameters as references.

Comment: You are not calling the function you are just declaring the function

Comment: Thank you guys for your help - I didn't understand completely at first but you led me to think that the part of the code I was editing was only defining the function and not actually executing it so that prompted to look for "star_cloudprnt_print_address" later on in the code and I found it at the bottom where it was called up. I added the same code in this part instead and it worked a treat (thanks again!):

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help - I didn't understand completely at first but you led me to think that the part of the code I was editing was only defining the function and not actually executing it so that prompted to look for "star_cloudprnt_print_address" later on in the code and I found it at the bottom where it was called up. I added the same code in this part instead and it worked a treat (thanks again!):

```
*       Generate printer receipt/ticket data
    */
    star_cloudprnt_print_receipt_header($printer, $selectedPrinter, $order, $order_meta);
    
    star_cloudprnt_print_items_header($printer, $selectedPrinter, $order, $order_meta);
    star_cloudprnt_print_items($printer, $selectedPrinter, $order, $order_meta);
    star_cloudprnt_print_coupon_info($printer, $selectedPrinter, $order, $order_meta);
    star_cloudprnt_print_item_totals($printer, $selectedPrinter, $order, $order_meta);
    star_cloudprnt_print_items_footer($printer, $selectedPrinter, $order, $order_meta);
    
    star_cloudprnt_print_additional_order_info($printer, $selectedPrinter, $order, $order_meta);
    $swift_order_type = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_zh_shipping_type') ? get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_zh_shipping_type')[0] : '';;
    if ($swift_order_type == delivery ){
    star_cloudprnt_print_address($printer, $selectedPrinter, $order, $order_meta);
    }
    star_cloudprnt_print_customer_notes($printer, $selectedPrinter, $order, $order_meta);

    star_cloudprnt_print_receipt_footer($printer, $selectedPrinter, $order, $order_meta);

    $printer->cut();
```